# TFS Build Agent and Office PIA

Tags: c#, tfs, interop, ms-office, office-2007

I'm currently investigation TFS 2012 automated builds/build agents

The situation I have is that I have:

- A legacy solution that builds Office 2007 Addins
- A test build controller
- Two test build agents, one in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012
- No visual studio or office installed on a build agent.

In order to get the build agent to compile the project, I need to install the Office 2007 PIA libraries installed on the build agent.  I've managed to do this on the Windows 7 machine, because it had office on it, as part of the standard image.

However the Server 2012 machine does not, as it's a windows server.

When I try to install Office 2007 PIA redistributable library, it stops me because Office is not installed.  My first thought is that I should be reluctant to install office because:

- It's office, I shouldn't install office on a server
- I have to investigate licensing

Is there a way of installing the Office 2007 PIA on windows server without office?

I'm ok with manual install if I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install office in order to satisfy the pre-install requirements for the pia library

Answer (score 1):

The standalone redistributable can be found here and unless they have changed the requirements office does not need to be installed.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

Comment: Our current build uses the 2007 Office PIA, and updating to 2010 PIA means that we'll most likely have to go through a testing round to as it's a code change.  The 2007 PIA redistributable has an Office Install launch condition

Comment: In that case you have no choice but to install office on your build server.

Comment: Yea, that's what I did in the end, if you repost/edit that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks